# Comma after "of course" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I just wrote this sentence (shortened, so not literally) on a different StackExchange site:

> Of course it's very easy to purge the exact packages which have been
>   installed by that if you still have the output.

Should the be a comma after "Of course"? Had I written something like "Evidently, it's very easy to ...", I'd feel like there should be a comma in there. But the above sentence doesn't feel right with a comma nor does it feel right without one.

Comment: I think it can go either way, but the meaning of "of course" changes slightly with or without the comma.

Comment: @J.R. Could you please explain the difference in the meaning of "of course" with and without the comma?

Comment: @Anonymous - See [32a and 32b](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of--course). It's just a matter of personal opinion, of course, but I think the O.P.'s sentence reads slightly differently with or without the comma.

Comment: I don't think the meaning changes very much. A more a matter of emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is the same either way. *However*, when writing sentences - especially when writing something formal such as an essay - one should use commas after their transition word or phrase that starts a new sentence.

*For example*, notice how I started this sentence with my transition phrase "for example" and put a comma after it? *Of course*, commas are useful for starting sentences out, as well as breaking up the thoughts in a single sentence.

I italicized the transition words/phrases above. [Here](http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Transitions.html) is a site with phrases if you want to know how to add variety to your words. It's divided into different categories.

Comment: I think you should use a better example, because it feels **wrong** to start a sentence with "for example" *without the comma*, whereas "of course" feels different. I am a native speaker and usually I can figure out a reason, but I can't figure out one here.