# comma after "Firstly" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

A post ([Comma after "of course" at the beginning of a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/103811/109190)) gives a clear rule/suggestion about the usage of comma after the transition words/phrases at the beginning of a sentence.

> ... one **should use commas** after their transition word or phrase that starts a new sentence.

However, the example sentences in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/first-firstly-or-at-first) seem to invalidate this rule.

> **Firstly** I would like to thank you for your kind offer of a job …
>
> **Firstly** the sodium chloride is dissolved in the water and heated gently.

Is the comma in this case required, optional or unnecessary? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an editor, I would  always put a comma in the text if it were not there.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/definition/firstly  Click *more example sentences*. They do have a comma right after **firstly**. (Some examples have, some don't. Not sure why). I *always* put a comma after *firstly, secondly* etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/commas-after-introductory-words/)

> Introductory words, like introductory phrases, require a comma. After introductory words, we use a comma to separate the introductory word from the independent clause.

Unless there are other words following an introductory word (e.g., firstly, however), a comma should follow the introductory word.  If there are words with the introductory word, then the comma follows the phrase:

> Firstly in my response, I would like to thank you for your kind offer of a job …
>
> Firstly in our demonstration, the sodium chloride is dissolved in the water and heated gently.
>
> However wonderful the gala might be, I cannot attend.

If the introductory word stands alone, it is followed by a comma.  As to use with words like "firstly", I suppose to use or not could be a matter of style.  However, punctuation is utilized for clarity and often parrots speech where a breath would be taken.  As such, a comma after "firstly" would seem in order.

Comment: Thank you. So, there should have been a comma follows "Firstly", in the example sentences from Cambridge Dictionary, right?

Comment: Correct.  The page about "First, Firstly, or at First" is carelessly edited in the comma regard.  Another page  on Cambridge (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/firstly) shows a consistency with regard to use of comma after "Firstly".

Comment: The webpage given in the post you reference is an excellent reference for this matter ... https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/style/transitions/ ... keep that at hand to address transitionals.